# linking GameViewController.swift to GameScene.swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have created a UI elements on main.storyboard which i require to be hidden until the game is over and the once the player tap the screen to dismiss. Main.storyboard is linked to GameViewController therefor all my IBOutlets and IBActions are in there and all my game code is in GameScene. How can i link the view controller to the scene for that the popup image and buttons only appear when it is game over. Would greatly appreciate some help, I have been stuck on this for quite some time now.

Comment: this is a fundamental issue of the perceived "ease of use" Apple promotes SpriteKit as having. It's not easy to use, and there are dozens of things that need to be understood in profound ways. I wish I could help, but I'm still struggling with grokking all the ways to own/see/talk between scenes, views, view controllers and methods and instances within the game world. So don't panic that this doesn't seem immediately obvious, and take the time to read CrashOverRide and a few others around here, as they know a lot, and aren't even aware just how much they know. It's easy for them. Somehow

Comment: @Confused Thank you for that, I was get frustated and losing hope. I wish it would just click! CrashOverRides method seems the best way. I have managed to get the button to show on the screen as a SKSprite Nodes with my game over pop up, just working on getting the share feature to work to allow the user to post on social media.

Comment: @Confused Check my answer to this question, particularly the first few paragraphs. Hopefully that helps you understand on a basic level the difference between ViewControllers, SKScenes and when to use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be quite a common problem people have with SpriteKit games so lets go through the difference between SpriteKit games and UIKit apps.

When you make a regular UIKit app, e.g. YouTube, Facebook, you would use ViewControllers, CollectionViews, Views etc for each screen/menu that you see (Home screen, Channel screen, Subscription channel screen etc). So you would use UIKit APIs for this such as UIButtons, UIImageViews, UILabels, UIViews, UICollectionViews etc. To do this visually we would use storyboards.

In SpriteKit games on the other hand it works differently. You work with SKScenes for each screen that you see (MenuScene, SettingsScene, GameScene, GameOverScene etc) and only have 1 ViewController (GameViewController). That GameViewController, which has a SKView in it, will present all your SKScenes.

So we should add our UI directly in the relevant SKScenes using SpriteKit APIs such as SKLabelNodes, SKSpriteNodes, SKNodes etc. To do this visually we would use the SpriteKit scene level editor and not storyboards.

So the general logic would be to load your 1st SKScene as usual from the GameViewController and than do the rest from within the relevant SKScenes. Your GameViewController should basically have next to no code in it beyond the default code. You can also transition from 1 scene to another scene very easily (GameScene -> GameOverScene).

If you use GameViewController for your UI it will get messy really quickly if you have multiple SKScenes because UI will be added to GameViewController and therefore all SKScenes. So you would have to remove/show UI when you transition between scenes and it would be madness.

To add a label in SpriteKit it would be something like this

```
 class GameScene: SKScene {

  lazy var scoreLabel: SKLabelNode = {
      let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "HelveticaNeue")
      label.text = "SomeText"
      label.fontSize = 22
      label.fontColor = .yellow
      label.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
      return label
  }()

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

      addChild(scoreLabel)
  }
}
```

To make buttons you essentially create a SKSpriteNode and give it a name and then look for it in touchesBegan or touchesEnded and run an SKAction on it for animation and some code after.

```
enum ButtonName: String {
     case play
     case share
}

class GameScene: SKScene {

       lazy var shareButton: SKSpriteNode = {
            let button = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ShareButton")
            button.name = ButtonName.share.rawValue
            button.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
            return button
        }()

       override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

             addChild(shareButton)
       }

       /// Touches began
       override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

             for touch in touches {
                 let location = touch.location(in: self)
                 let node = atPoint(location)

                 if let nodeName = node.name {
                      switch nodeName {
                      case ButtonName.play.rawValue:
                          // run some SKAction animation and some code
                      case ButtonName.share.rawValue:

                          let action1 = SKAction.scale(to: 0.9, duration: 0.2)
                          let action2 = SKAction.scale(to: 1, duration: 0.2)
                          let action3 = SKAction.run { [weak self] in
                             self?.openShareMenu(value: "\(self!.score)", image: nil) // image is nil in this example, if you use a image just create a UIImage and pass it into the method
                          }
                          let sequence = SKAction.sequence([action1, action2, action3])
                          node.run(sequence)

                      default: 
                          break
                    }
               }
          }
     }
}
```

To make this even easier I would create a button helper class, for a simple example have a look at this
https://nathandemick.com/2014/09/buttons-sprite-kit-using-swift/

You can also check out Apple's sample game DemoBots for a more feature rich example.

This way you can have things such as animations etc in the helper class and don't have to repeat code for each button.

For sharing, I would actually use UIActivityController instead of those older Social APIs which might become deprecated soon. This also allows you to share to multiple services via 1 UI and you will also only need 1 share button in your app. It could be a simple function like this in the SKScene you are calling it from.

```
func openShareMenu(value: String, image: UIImage?) {
    guard let view = view else { return }

    // Activity items
    var activityItems = [AnyObject]()

    // Text
    let text = "Can you beat my score " + value
    activityItems.append(text as AnyObject)

    // Add image if valid
    if let image = image {
        activityItems.append(image)
    }

    // Activity controller
    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)

    // iPad settings
    if Device.isPad {
        activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
        activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
        activityController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.init(rawValue: 0)
    }

    // Excluded activity types
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = [
        UIActivityType.airDrop,
        UIActivityType.print,
        UIActivityType.assignToContact,
        UIActivityType.addToReadingList,
    ]

    // Present
    view.window?.rootViewController?.present(activityController, animated: true)
}
```

and then call it like so when the correct button was pressed (see above example)

```
openShareMenu(value: "\(self.score)", image: SOMEUIIMAGE)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If i create the gameOverPopUp as a SKSpriteNode i can get it to appear and dissapear how i want but how to add a action to when the button is pressed? like the IBAction runs when the a button is pressed how can i achieve that same effect with SpriteNodes?

Comment: Yes you should use SKNodes/SKSpriteNodes for your gameOver pop up menu. To add buttons you would simply add the sprites to the gameOverMenu and look for them in touches began to see if a button was pressed and than run an SKAction to animate it. Even better would be creating a button helper class to manage this for you, a simple example would be this https://nathandemick.com/2014/09/buttons-sprite-kit-using-swift/  For a more feature rich example you should check out apples game DemoBots.

Comment: can i run an SKAction to post on facebook and twitter? That was my reason to creating IBAction in ViewController as it is easier to make the use post on social networks

Comment: I would actually not use those APIs, they are older. For sharing you should now use UIActivityController where you can share to multiple services with 1 UI and you also only need 1 button. So the general idea would be to run the SKAction to animate your button when it was pressed and than when the animation is finished run the code to present the UIActivityController. There is quite a few tutorials about UIActivityController, just google them. To present a ViewController such as UIActivityController in SpriteKit scenes you can say this view?.window?.rootViewController.present(...).

Comment: I have updated my answer with more detail including UIActivityController example. Let me know how it goes

Comment: I have edited my above code and added what you have suggested. I can now get the gameOverPopup to appear with the share button, just not sure on where and how to implement the final line you suggested to call it. At the moment when i press the share button the game restarts as the whole screen is tap to play again. I only have one SKScene which contains the whole game. Thank you for your help so far if you could just help me finish it off i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hey, I am glad it helps. What do you mean by the final line? When the share button is pressed you should call the openShareMenu function.

Comment: Yes the line to call the function, where would i implement that into my code?

Comment: I updated my answer. Go to the touches began bit and check the switch statement. I added a simple SKAction to animate the button and than call the function. You should really subclass your buttons, like in the links in my question or DemoBots, so you dont have to repeat alot of code when you add more buttons. Keep me posted

Comment: This is a great answer, but for those that come to SpriteKit without UIKit experience/knowledge/understanding.

Comment: btw this is not so much a criticism of your answer as it is a furtherance of my comment on the OP's question... that the pre-existing context from which a person comes at and begins to learn SpriteKit matters, too.

Comment: Yeah. The most issues I see is actually people coming from UIKit (regular apps) to SpriteKit and they use the UIKit stuff. If you start straight with SpriteKit I think its easier because you dont have the habits of doing things that you would do in a normal app, like using UIKit APIs.

Answer (score 2):

create reference of GameViewController in GameScene class like this way

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var referenceOfGameViewController : GameViewController!

}
```

in GameViewController pass the reference like this way

```
   class GameViewController: UIViewController {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
    // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
     if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            scene.referenceOfGameViewController = self
            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }


    view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    view.showsFPS = true
    view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
  }
}
```

by using this line you can pass reference to  GameScene class

```
        scene.referenceOfGameViewController = self
```

Now In GameScene class you can access all the variable of  GameViewController like this way

```
referenceOfGameViewController.fbButton.hidden = false
referenceOfGameViewController.gameOverPopUP.hidden = false
```

Comment: when i add:   var referenceOfGameViewController = GameViewController!  the error saying: Expected member name or constructor call after type name.
and for the line : scene.referenceOfGameViewController = self I get the error Value of type SKScene has no member 'referenceOfGameViewController'

Comment: add 
var referenceOfGameViewController : GameViewController!

Comment: don't write var referenceOfGameViewController = GameViewController!

                                                            write 

              var referenceOfGameViewController : GameViewController!

Comment: in GameViewController.swift I am still getting an error which says, Value of type 'SKScene' has no member 'referenceGameViewController'