# ImageView and Buttons show/hide in sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a ImageView and Buttons that i have created in main.storyboard. I have IBOutlets and IBActions for the buttons.
I have managed to hide them in the gameViewController however they stay hidden all the time. How can i refer to these in my GameScene so i can chose when to hide and show them in GameScene when the game is over.

Comment: you are using UIImageView And UIButton  class IBOutlets ?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Imaging your button outlet name is myButton. So wherever you wants to hide call it as myButton.isHidden= true. And wherevr u wants to show it set it as false

Comment: I have set is hidden as true in the viewcontroller.swift but because my game code is in GameScene.swift I cant trigger it to be false when the game is over. If you have a look here I have put my code in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667861/linking-gameviewcontroller-swift-to-gamescene-swift

Comment: referenceOfGameviewcontroller.YourButton.hidden = false

Answer (score 0):

In "gamescene" controller get the reference of "gameviewcontroller" then you can access in "gamescene" controller  as

```
referenceOfGameviewcontroller.YourButton.hidden = false
```

Comment: sorry i am new to swift, how do you reference before adding the below line? my code is attached here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667861/linking-gameviewcontroller-swift-to-gamescene-swift

Comment: check my answer in your question link