# How to add a ViewController to an SKScene

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, swift3

I have the following view controller in my SpriteKit game:

```
import UIKit

class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = .red
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.isPagingEnabled = true
    return cv
}()


let cellId = "cellId"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(collectionView)

    //use autolayout instead
    collectionView.anchorToTop(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor)

    collectionView.register(PageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath as IndexPath)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
  }

}

extension UIView {

func anchorToTop(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil) {

    anchorWithConstantsToTop(top: top, left: left, bottom: bottom, right: right, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0)
}

func anchorWithConstantsToTop(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, topConstant: CGFloat = 0, leftConstant: CGFloat = 0, bottomConstant: CGFloat = 0, rightConstant: CGFloat = 0) {

    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    if let top = top {
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: topConstant).isActive = true
    }

    if let bottom = bottom {
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -bottomConstant).isActive = true
    }

    if let left = left {
        leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: leftConstant).isActive = true
    }

    if let right = right {
        rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -rightConstant).isActive = true
    }

}

}
```

I tried initializing it in the following way in my `SKScene`:

```
    override init(size: CGSize){
    super.init(size: size)
    weak var myViewController: MyViewController!

    myViewController = MyViewController(frame: self.frame)
    self.view?.addSubview(myViewController)    
}
```

The above gave me the following errors:

```
"incorrect argument label in call (have 'frame:', expected 'coder:')"
```

and

```
"cannot convert type of 'MyViewController!' to expected argument type 'UIView'"
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong. How can add my view controller to the `SKScene`?

**UPDATE**

I am trying to make a menu for my game using `UICollectionView` that is why I was trying to add a the view controller above (now showing the full MenuViewController code) to my `SKScene`. But now I get the idea that I should be adding it to my SKView instead. I believe this view can be added to the `SKView` from my `SKScene` class (below). How can this be done?

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

private var label : SKLabelNode?
private var spinnyNode : SKShapeNode?



override func didMove(to view: SKView) {



}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let label = self.label {
        label.run(SKAction.init(named: "Pulse")!, withKey: "fadeInOut")
    }

}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}


}
```

Comment: Have you tried self.view?.addSubview(myViewController.view)

Comment: Also, is your UIViewController subclass a xib or storyboard?

Comment: `self.view?.addSubview(myViewController.view)` has solved one of the errors. What about the other one - `incorrect argument label in call (have 'frame:', expected 'coder:')`? Also I am creating my view controller programmatically, I prefer this approach to the storyboard.

Comment: You are confusing yourself on a lot of things.  You need to look at some tutorials and understand what a ViewController is, a View is, an SKScene is, and what SKNodes are. Then you need to learn how they all interact with each other.  I would recommend learning the objects in the order that I gave you. A SO answer will not help you out unless somebody is willing to write a ton of info on the matter.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40676759/6728196. You need to know this stuff.

Comment: UIKit and SpriteKit are 2 different libraries. You are trying to use a UIKit element in a SpriteKit game, which sometimes make it difficult to implement.

Comment: I just updated the question

Comment: only view controllers can present other view controllers, you need to step back, evaluate your project, and determine if what you want makes sense.  Write your ideas down on a piece of paper if you have to.  Then tackle your problems piece by piece.  I can guarantee you every question you have on the matter has been answered before on SO.

Comment: Okay, now you're confusing me. Can't a view controller be accessed from an SKScene?

Comment: no, view controllers can't even be accessed from views (natively), they need to either be messaged, have some kind of delegate set up that allows for the view controller to be accessed, or the worst possible way: grab it from the sharedApplicatation singleton/method

Answer (score 1):

The answer was too long for a comment but in regards to this issue: `incorrect argument label in call (have 'frame:', expected 'coder:')` is because you're creating a new `MyViewController` object and initializing it with an argument label of `frame` whether you even do have that as an initializer for your class or not is the issue.

We need to see your `MyViewController` class and what initializers you have set up because it seems that your class has only 1 initializer, and it seems to be `init(coder: NSCoder)`.
Please show us your `MyViewController` class.

Comment: If you wanted to make a comment longer than the max length, just add ... to the end of the first, then continue in a second comment. I think this would be better served as a comment

Answer (score -2):

Simple answer is you can't.  SpriteKit and UIKit are 2 different animals and they are only joined together through SKView.

Comment: I think what they're trying to do is add a level selection view into their spritekit game just like flappy bird's level selection view, etc. But just a badly worded question.

Comment: oh I know what they are trying to do, that is why I commented on his question

Comment: This is the correct answer for the given question. You can't add a view to the scene. Scene is presented by the view (SKView)... It should be really nice that downvoting is not possible without leaving a comment.

Comment: @Whirlwind, I agree on that, thank you for the comment

Comment: I agree with you guys, this is a correct answer. Maybe people downvote it due to it should possibly be a comment (but there is the FLAG option) or simply they don't understand OP question about viewController, not simply view. I don't know. BTW, this is correct.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I have provided a comment for the user, and an answer for anybody else who sees this question in the future looking for an answer to it.