# SpriteKit: Add a node to view?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm new to Xcode 7, how do I add a black node in SpriteKit?

Can anyone point me in the right direction or link me up with any tutorials please? Thank you

Comment: There is an initializer which takes color for an argument. So you just pass .black to it. I think this is more suitable for  what you are trying to achive in compare to creating sprite with an image (from the answer below).

Answer (score 3):

You want to create a new SKSpriteNode object, and add it to the view

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var node: SKSpriteNode?

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BlackNode.png")
        node.position.x = self.size.width / 2
        node.position.y = self.size.height / 2
        addChild(node)
    }
}
```

So in your GameScene class (or whatever SKScene class you are using), this creates a SKSpriteNode that is the image of whatever "BlackNode.png" is, and sets its position to the center of the screen, and adds it to scene

Comment: Please note that `node.position.x = self.size.width / 2` and `node.position.y = self.size.height / 2` will place the node in the __upper right corner__ of the scene. If you want to center the SKSpriteNode you just need to remove that 2 lines: in this case `node.position` will be `(0, 0)` which is the center of the scene.

Comment: It's easier to use `node.position = CGPoint(x: ##, y: ##)` instead.

Comment: @appzYourLife I'm not talking about centering, I'm saying in general when choosing the position of a node, it's easier to use a CGPoint rather than access x and y separately.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your question is asking how to add an all black node to the scene, try this:

```
override func didMoveTo(view: SKView) {

    let node = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.black, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)) // Declare and initialize node
    addChild(node) // Function that adds node to scene

}
```

This uses the SKSpriteNode initializer [`init(color: UIColor, size: CGSize)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skspritenode/1519762-init), which you would pass a color for the node and size. This is then used to create a rectangle, while the nodes `texture` property remains `nil`.

Note that in this example, no position is explicitly chosen, so the default (0,0) is chosen (centre of scene if scene `anchorPoint` is 0.5,0.5)

To get a further understanding of scenes vs views and SpriteKit vs UIKit (which I think is where you're having trouble) check out this answer: [SpriteKit vs UIKit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40676759/6728196)